# Web Scraping Rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping

I've tried to read the text of this article, however I obtain just character(0)

```
 library(rvest)
 tex <- read_html("http://semanaeconomica.com/article/sectores-y-empresas/transporte/360660-renegociar-si-anular-no/")
 p_text <- tex %>%
 html_nodes("section") %>%
 html_nodes("#text") %>%
 html_text()%>%print()
```

I'm not an expert in web scraping, so I will be very grateful by your help!

Comment: I don't see anything on that page that would match the selector `#text`

Comment: Looks like the content is generated using JavaScript, so you'll need something else than `rvest` (the options are either tools generating JavaScript e.g. `PhantomJS`, `Selenium` or emulating the request generating the content sometimes works as well).

Comment: camille, at the moment to select the main text of the article in the console you  will obtain a node <p>, inside is the text which is tag as #text.....

Comment: I think the options include the decapitated package that interfaces with the Chrome headless browser capabilities. I needed to install that version of the browser as well. I think there are examples of that package on SO offered by its author: @hrbmstr

Comment: That's just a marker of the nodes' inner text. `html_nodes` needs a CSS or Xpath selector—`#text` would be a CSS selector for a node with the ID "text," but that doesn't exist. [Here's](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) a diagram. `#text` is the stuff that would be returned by calling `html_text` on a valid node

Comment: @camille you are right, thanks to explain me that point...In fact, I was trying with other correct nodes, but I obtained a problem that I explained here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56269752/web-scrapping-log-in) ...Thanks by your help!

Comment: Is this now solved?

Comment: @QHarr not, yet

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to obtain the text in the page using the following code :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
url <- "http://semanaeconomica.com/article/sectores-y-empresas/transporte/360660-renegociar-si-anular-no/"
IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
IEApp$Navigate(url)
Sys.sleep(5)
doc <- IEApp$Document()
web_Obj <- doc$querySelector("body > div.container.se-container.se-container--sm.mb60 > div > div.se-article__body.fixed-to-pos.pl55-md.mb60 > div")
txt <- web_Obj$innerText()
txt <- strsplit(txt, "\n|\r")[[1]]
txt <- txt[txt != ""]
txt

[1] "Como una veleta que se mueve según los vientos de la indignación ciudadana, el alcalde Jorge Muñoz anunció que el Concejo Metropolitano evaluará la anulación de los contratos de Rutas de Lim... "                   
 [2] "¿QUIERE LEER LA HISTORIA COMPLETA?"                                                                                                                                                                                   
 [3] "Regístrese y obtenga 3 artículos gratis al mes y el boletín informativo."                                                                                                                                             
 [4] "Suscríbase para acceso ilimitado"                                                                                                                                                                                     
 [5] "  "                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 [6] "   DNI  "                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 [7] "   Carnet de extranjería  "                                                                                                                                                                                           
 [8] " "                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 [9] " "                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[10] " "                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[11] " "                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[12] " "                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[13] "  "                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[14] "Se requiere al menos 8 caracteres, una mayúscula, una minúscula y un número"                                                                                                                                          
[15] "   "                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[16] "   Acepto los términos y condiciones y las políticas de privacidad  "                                                                                                                                                 
[17] "Regístrese y continúe leyendo "                                                                                                                                                                                       
[18] "¿Ya tiene una cuenta? Inicie sesión "                                                                                                                                                                                 
[19] " grecaptcha.ready(function() { grecaptcha.execute('6LfO_LAZAAAAANQMr4R1KnhUFziP2QJsCQqUCHXR', {action: 'submit'}).then(function(token) { if (token) { document.getElementById('recaptcha').value = token; } }); });  "
```